# Android - Signed Application Gives a force close, but Unsigned .apk not

Tags: android, package

I'm exporting my signed application and it gives a force close. But normally the unsigned version of the same app working correctly. How can i solve this?

Any Suggestions?

This is my apps log

```
08-17 14:58:00.000: V/AlarmManager(132): --- from triggerAlarmsLocked operation: 

com.acer.android.widget.digitalclock
08-17 14:58:00.000: I/AlarmManager(132): ----Alarm type: 1Second:1345215600.0
08-17 14:58:00.000: I/AlarmManager(132): Alarm type : 1, from setRepeating operation : android
08-17 14:58:00.000: I/AlarmManager(132): ----Alarm type: 1Second:1345215540.0
08-17 14:58:00.170: V/AlarmManager(132): --- from triggerAlarmsLocked operation: com.google.android.gsf
08-17 14:58:00.170: I/AlarmManager(132): ----Alarm type: 0Second:1345216639.530000000
08-17 14:58:01.040: D/Finsky(643): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
08-17 14:58:02.700: D/AndroidRuntime(6545): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-17 14:58:02.700: D/AndroidRuntime(6545): CheckJNI is OFF
08-17 14:58:02.810: D/AndroidRuntime(6545): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
08-17 14:58:02.810: D/AndroidRuntime(6545): Shutting down VM
08-17 14:58:02.810: I/AndroidRuntime(6545): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-17 14:58:02.820: D/dalvikvm(6545): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 87% free 337K/2560K, paused 0ms+0ms
08-17 14:58:02.820: D/dalvikvm(6545): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-17 14:58:04.000: D/AndroidRuntime(6556): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-17 14:58:04.000: D/AndroidRuntime(6556): CheckJNI is OFF
08-17 14:58:04.130: D/AndroidRuntime(6556): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
08-17 14:58:04.170: D/dalvikvm(819): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 11% free 6338K/7047K, paused 2ms+2ms
08-17 14:58:04.170: W/ActivityManager(132): No content provider found for: 
08-17 14:58:04.190: D/PackageParser(132): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl1300267645.tmp
08-17 14:58:04.190: W/ActivityManager(132): No content provider found for: 
08-17 14:58:04.440: D/dalvikvm(132): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1889K, 38% free 17760K/28359K, paused 2ms+6ms
08-17 14:58:04.450: D/PackageManager(132): Scanning package air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi
08-17 14:58:04.450: I/PackageManager(132): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi-1.apk
08-17 14:58:04.590: D/dalvikvm(6565): DexOpt: load 10ms, verify+opt 87ms
08-17 14:58:04.640: D/PackageManager(132):   Activities: air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.BilgiYarismasiActivity air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.SoruGonderSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.KategoriSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.YarismaSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.OyunBittiSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.AyarlarSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.SkorGonderSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.SkorGonderildiSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.OdulluYarismaSayfasi air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi.FacebookLib
08-17 14:58:04.640: I/ActivityManager(132): Force stopping package air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi uid=10077
08-17 14:58:04.740: D/PackageManager(132): New package installed in /data/app/air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi-1.apk
08-17 14:58:04.920: D/PackageManager(132): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 4 services unchanged
08-17 14:58:04.940: I/Launcher(216): setLoadOnResume
08-17 14:58:04.950: D/GTalkService(257): [GTalkService.1] handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
08-17 14:58:04.950: D/GTalkService(257): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
08-17 14:58:04.970: I/AlarmManager(132): Alarm type : 0, from setRepeating operation : com.android.vending
08-17 14:58:04.970: D/PackageManager(132): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 13 services unchanged
08-17 14:58:04.970: I/AlarmManager(132): ----Alarm type: 0Second:1345215499.982000000
08-17 14:58:04.980: I/AccountTypeManager(280): Loaded meta-data for 3 account types, 2 accounts in 5ms
08-17 14:58:05.020: D/dalvikvm(280): GC_CONCURRENT freed 380K, 9% free 6831K/7495K, paused 37ms+13ms
08-17 14:58:05.190: D/dalvikvm(132): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1148K, 38% free 17834K/28359K, paused 5ms+13ms
08-17 14:58:05.190: D/AndroidRuntime(6556): Shutting down VM
08-17 14:58:05.200: D/dalvikvm(6556): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 87% free 341K/2560K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-17 14:58:05.200: D/jdwp(6556): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-17 14:58:05.200: D/dalvikvm(6556): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-17 14:58:05.210: I/AndroidRuntime(6556): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-17 14:58:05.300: D/BatteryService(132): level:12 scale:100 status:3 health:2 present:true voltage: 3675 temperature: 309 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:false icon:17302707 invalid charger:0
08-17 14:58:05.360: D/dalvikvm(216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2654K, 45% free 13381K/24007K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-17 14:58:05.370: D/AndroidRuntime(6571): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-17 14:58:05.370: D/AndroidRuntime(6571): CheckJNI is OFF
08-17 14:58:05.510: D/AndroidRuntime(6571): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
08-17 14:58:05.510: I/ActivityManager(132): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi/.BilgiYarismasiActivity } from pid 6571
08-17 14:58:05.530: D/AndroidRuntime(6571): Shutting down VM
08-17 14:58:05.530: I/AndroidRuntime(6571): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-17 14:58:05.540: D/dalvikvm(216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1927K, 44% free 13500K/24007K, paused 2ms+10ms
08-17 14:58:05.540: D/dalvikvm(6571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 86% free 368K/2560K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-17 14:58:05.540: D/jdwp(6571): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-17 14:58:05.540: D/dalvikvm(6571): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-17 14:58:05.550: I/ActivityManager(132): Start proc air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi for activity air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi/.BilgiYarismasiActivity: pid=6580 uid=10077 gids={3003}
08-17 14:58:05.620: D/TabletStatusBar(186): lights on
08-17 14:58:05.680: D/dalvikvm(6580): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 5% free 6360K/6659K, paused 31ms
08-17 14:58:05.690: I/dalvikvm-heap(6580): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.775MB for 1536016-byte allocation
08-17 14:58:05.770: D/dalvikvm(6580): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 7860K/8199K, paused 2ms+3ms
08-17 14:58:05.830: D/dalvikvm(216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1730K, 43% free 13778K/24007K, paused 2ms+9ms
08-17 14:58:05.870: D/dalvikvm(6580): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 27K, 3% free 8004K/8199K, paused 33ms
08-17 14:58:05.940: D/dalvikvm(6580): GC_CONCURRENT freed 43K, 3% free 8528K/8711K, paused 3ms+5ms
08-17 14:58:05.990: I/ActivityManager(132): Starting: Intent { cmp=air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi/.AyarlarSayfasi (has extras) } from pid 6580
08-17 14:58:06.040: D/HAL(6580): [HAL] hw_get_module:share library path:/system/lib/hw/gralloc.tegra.so
08-17 14:58:06.360: I/ActivityManager(132): Displayed air.com.cepall.bilgiyarismasi/.AyarlarSayfasi: +317ms (total +817ms)
08-17 14:58:06.360: D/TabletStatusBar(186): lights on
08-17 14:58:06.380: I/ActivityManager(132): No longer want com.metago.astro (pid 6019): hidden #16
08-17 14:58:08.250: D/dalvikvm(6580): GC_CONCURRENT freed 236K, 5% free 8952K/9351K, paused 2ms+2ms
08-17 14:58:12.220: D/dalvikvm(829): GC_EXPLICIT freed 79K, 6% free 7199K/7623K, paused 4ms+2ms
08-17 14:58:12.530: D/TabletStatusBar(186): lights on
08-17 14:58:12.540: W/InputManagerService(132): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41ccb688 (uid=1000 pid=6176)
08-17 14:58:12.740: D/dalvikvm(205): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2497K, 30% free 7589K/10695K, paused 29ms
08-17 14:58:12.740: I/dalvikvm-heap(205): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.271MB for 1848336-byte allocation
08-17 14:58:12.780: D/dalvikvm(205): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 13% free 9394K/10695K, paused 3ms+2ms
08-17 14:58:17.820: D/dalvikvm(879): GC_EXPLICIT freed 33K, 6% free 6506K/6919K, paused 14ms+2ms
08-17 14:58:19.970: V/AlarmManager(132): --- from triggerAlarmsLocked operation: com.google.android.gsf
08-17 14:58:19.970: I/AlarmManager(132): ----Alarm type: 0Second:1345216639.530000000
08-17 14:58:20.130: D/Finsky(643): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
```

Comment: you should post the logcat. all apps need to be signed. You cannot run an unsigned app on android

Comment: nothing to do with logcat. because it is a working application. When i sign and export it and install it manually on device it gives a force close.

Comment: so post the call stack. force close means some exception would have occured

Comment: this log is during installation. do post the log when you launch app from launcher

Comment: @CodersParadise were you able to solve this??

Comment: I solved it but i dont really remember how? But I have a guess clean and rebuild the project and again sign the application.